# Font icons are showing differently on two different installs

Tags: css, fonts, icons, wordpress-theming, font-face

I am using this font icon set that I made with the icomoon font generator: http://bbmthemes.com/work/icons70897/

On my development install: http://bbmthemes.com/themes/smart/full-width-page/

..the font is displaying the correct icons that I want in each place, for example if you use firebug to inspect the search glass icon in the top right and enter this into the div.search..

```
&#xe164;
```

..you will see that it matches the magnifying glass icon that is already there, as well as matching up to the magnifying glass icon marked as..

```
&#xe164;
```

..on the font demo link above.

However, on the live version: http://www.bbmthemes.com/themes/modular/?page_id=2

..that I just installed the codes are all showing the icon previous to the number that is supposed to be displayed.  So for example, the code is exactly the same to display that search magnifying glass:

```
&#xe164;
```

..but it displays an audio icon which in the font demo is marked as..

```
&#xe163;
```

I have no idea how or why this is happening.  Does anyone have any idea?

**EDIT** Is this fixed?  A friend told me he sees the magnifying glass on both but mine still shows the audio icon on the second.  I can't tell if its just the cache not updating.  Do you see a magnifying glass on both links?

Comment: Sorry for this useless comment but I'm in love with this design.

Comment: I think it is fixed. Try deleting your cache, it's fine for me